# When is $gng^{-1} \not = n$?

Tags: inverse, normal-subgroups

Let's take [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of a normal subgroup:

> A subgroup, $N$, of a group, $G$, is called a normal subgroup if it is
>   invariant under conjugation; that is, the conjugation of an element of
>   $N$ by an element of $G$ is still in $N$: $\displaystyle
>  N\triangleleft G\,\Leftrightarrow \;\forall \;n\in N,\;\forall \ g\in
>  G\colon \;gng^{-1}\in N.$

Intuitively one could think that $gng^{-1} \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}gn = n\cdot1 $

But I assume, that this is not true for all $g \in G$.

Can you please provide a simple example for such a $g \in G$, so that $gng^{-1}\not = n$ ?

Comment: Take a look at [similar matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: consider affine transforms of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $g$ be a rotation of 180 deg and $n$ be any nonzero shift. then $gng^{-1}$ is the opposite shift of $n$.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer with a simpe example, @Max !

Comment: Thanksu, but I'm simply too lazy :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact $gng^{-1}=n$ iff $gn=ng$ i.e. $g$ and $n$ commute. Then you can take $2\times 2$ matrices or permutations on 3 objects.
$$
g=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\ ;\ 
n=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
hence 
$$
gng^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1& -1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2& -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\not=n
$$
For permutations, take $g=(1,2)=g^{-1}$ (exchange of $1$ and $2$) and $n=(2,3)$ (exchange of $2$ and $3$). Composing the permutations (as functions), one has 
$$
gng^{-1}(2)=gn(1)=g(1)=2\ ;\ n(1)=1
$$
thus $gng^{-1}\not=n$. Hope it helps !

Comment: Keep it simple! (I quite don't get your answer. Am I stupid?)

Comment: OK. I add details.